# apache2 - read configurations from MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache-2.2, configuration-management

I'm trying to move away from nasty daemons that write config files and need root access to operate.

I want to store vhosts/domains in an MySQL database, ideally with restricted access.
I'm looking for some modules that will be able to dynamically generate vhost config retrieving them using queries.

Some of what I found, and why I can't use it:

- [mod_sqltemplate](http://www.dmi.me.uk/code/apache/mod_sqltemplate/) - Exactly what I was looking for, until I realized it needs httpd reload when new vhosts are inserted to the database (meaning an external script/passwordless sudo/nasty daemons/etc)
- [mod_sqlinclude](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-sqlinclude/) - Looks the same as the above, but it's apache1.3 only. I also don't know if it requires httpd reload when new entries are inserted. I tried porting this myself and ended up [one function behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259102/apache2-module-development-apsrmcommandloop-replacement).
- mod_vdbh - I can't find any info on that one, but it has some references that shows that is might what I'm looking for
- [mod_shapvh](http://crazygreek.co.uk/content/mod_shapvh) - apache1.x only, failed to port it.

It would also be nice if there's a way to read/write bandwidth limit counters into MySQL.

Running on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: What OS are you running this on? From a google search of mod_vdbh, I see that it is in portage for Gentoo currently.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is **no** way to add virtual hosts to Apache without restarting it.

Comment: This blog post begs to differ - http://revjim.net/2003/08/14/mod_vdbh-for-apache/

Comment: Yes. And it also links directly to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

Comment: I don't understand how the module connects to a MySQL server? I want configurations stored completely in a database and not in configuration files.

Comment: It doesn't. What I was hinting at was that there might be a more efficient solution than storing and sourcing the vhost details from MySQL. Databases are great for some things, but others not so.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD hosts the patch for the mod_vdbh module: [**link**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/www/mod_vdbh/files/patch-mod_vdbh.c)

I don't know if apache really handles this well, without restarting the server. When I hosted my vhosts with lighttpd it required reboots to refresh the vhosts.